# What Would Happen If a .wav File Was All 1's or -1's?

Tags: audio, wav

To my understanding, .wav file is a list of numbers ranging from -1 to 1 (at least, if you are using a java class called WavFile to convert an array into a .wav file, the array must have values between -1 and 1). When you play a .wav file, those numbers are turned into voltages on your soundcard.

I have never tried this for the safety of my equipment, but if a .wav file was all 1's (max voltage), would your soundcard snap to full output voltage for the duration of the file? This would be very dangerous for headphones and receivers that the soundcard might be connected to, and it may be dangerous to the soundcard itself.

What I'm wondering is whether or not there is some built-in protection from this event in Windows OS.

Comment: wave files *do* have ones in them from time to time, and they don't destroy headphones/speakers/soundcards.  That's not the maximum voltage, that depends on the volume.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I left the phrase as "max voltage," because analog voltage at the soundcard definitely would depend on your volume. All I meant was the max voltage for your current volume setting. And of course, I'm talking about a wav file of sustained 1's or -1's for several seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the amplifier you use, typically the one in the sound card.  To have any effect at all it would need to be direct-coupled.  That's not common, most amplifiers are AC-coupled and block any DC offset on the signal to prevent the speaker from overheating.

Think of it as a high-pass filter, your WAV file has in effect a sound with a frequency of 0.  You won't hear anything, your ear can only perceive signals with a frequency between about 20 and 20,000 Hertz.  Nature's analog version of the Fast Fourier Transform.  Except when you start playing, you'll get a sudden spike from 0 to max.  Which produces a lot of high frequencies in the spectrum, you'll perceive this as a tick or pop.

Destroying equipment with data is an urban myth.  A simple workaround is to not turn the volume to 11.

Comment: Thanks! So in other words, the sound card would "try" to sit at it's maximum voltage, but some electrical components in the soundcard (coupling capacitor at the output) would prevent that from happening. That's very good to know.

Comment: In practice almost all audio systems implement a high-pass filter with the knee frequency positioned to avoid sending programme material below the frequency response of the transducers to them.